# Slideshows not working, what is the issue with my code? HTML CSS Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I use a Slideshow on my website to post images for blog articles. When I went to add more than one slideshow to my article, the slideshows stopped working altogether. Currently, if this code is ran as is, it will not load any of the images onto the screen. It would only show the arrows that can be clicked with no action occurring thereafter. I have below the code used for this in HTML, CSS, Javascript. If someone can somehow get this working for me, I would greatly appreciate it.

HTML:

```
<div class="mySlides1">
   <div class="numbertext">1 / 2</div>
   <img class="the-article-imgs-vert" src="/images/2022/04/image.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="the-article-imgs-caption">Text here</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides1">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 2</div>
    <img class="the-article-imgs" src="/images/2022/04/image-2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="the-article-imgs-caption">Text here</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;❮</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;❯</a>
```

```
<div class="mySlides2">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 2</div>
    <img src="/images/2022/04/photo_2022-04-02_19-33-27.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="the-article-imgs-caption">caption here</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides2">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 2</div>
    <img src="/images/2022/04/photo_2022-04-02_19-33-18.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="the-article-imgs-caption">caption .</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;❮</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;❯</a>
```

CSS:

```css
    /* Article Image */

.the-article-imgs {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 990px;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.the-article-imgs-caption {
  text-align: center;
}

.the-article-imgs-vert {
  height: 45%;
  max-width: 456px;
  min-width: 54%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

/* Slideshow Image Code */

* {box-sizing: border-box}

.mySlides, .mySlides1, .mySlides2, mySlides3, .mySlides4, .mySlides5, .mySlides6:first-of-type, {display: block;}

.mySlides, .mySlides1, .mySlides2, mySlides3, .mySlides4, .mySlides5, .mySlides6 {display: none;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text 
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}*/

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

Javascript:

```js
let slideIndex = [1,1];
let slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2"]
showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);

function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showSlides(n, no) {
  let i;
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the script needs to be downloaded in parallel to parsing the page. you need to add `async` when calling your js file `<script src="index.js" async></script>`

Comment: or add <script src="index.js"></script> at the bottom